# How can I find out image-id, instance-type, and subnet-id, which are available to my IAM user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have created a free tier account with AWS, and been following AWS CLI 2.0 documentation to get a EC2 VPC instance running. I have created a AWS root user, an IAM user and its access key, and EC2 key pair.

I saw the following command in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-services-ec2-instances.html:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-xxxxxxxx --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name MyKeyPair --security-group-ids sg-903004f8 --subnet-id subnet-6e7f829e
```

I was wondering how to find out the values to the following options `--image-id`, `--instance-type`, `-subnet-id`, which are available to my AWS account and IAM user?

Comment: I do not think there is a aws cli command for that. You have to check that in AWS docs and/or sometimes in aws console.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks. Could you be specific where I could find out the info?

Comment: Docs are https://aws.amazon.com/free/

Answer (score 2):

You can find out the values via the web console, but everything you can do in AWS you can do via API as well and most of the actions you can do with the CLI too. According to https://aws.amazon.com/free/?nc1=h_ls&all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=*all&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=*all the free tier offers only `t2.micro` or `t3.micro` instance types, but you can still list all the instance types to see more detailed information. Interestingly enough, right now I get only t1.micro and t2.micro as an output for the `FreeTierEligible=true` filter - see the example down it the text.

For subnets:

```
  describe-subnets
[--filters <value>]
[--subnet-ids <value>]
[--dry-run | --no-dry-run]
[--cli-input-json <value>]
[--starting-token <value>]
[--page-size <value>]
[--max-items <value>]
[--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

Example:

```
aws --region us-east-1 --output=json ec2 describe-subnets
```

Output:

```
{
"Subnets": [
    {
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1b",
        "AvailabilityZoneId": "use1-az4",
        "AvailableIpAddressCount": 4091,
        "CidrBlock": "172.31.0.0/20",
        "DefaultForAz": true,
        "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": true,
        "MapCustomerOwnedIpOnLaunch": false,
        "State": "available",
        "SubnetId": "subnet-xxxxx",
        "VpcId": "vpc-xxxxx",
        "OwnerId": "xxxxxxxx",
        "AssignIpv6AddressOnCreation": false,
        "Ipv6CidrBlockAssociationSet": [],
        "SubnetArn": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:xxxxxxxx:subnet/subnet-xxxxx",
        "EnableDns64": false,
        "Ipv6Native": false,
        "PrivateDnsNameOptionsOnLaunch": {
            "HostnameType": "ip-name",
            "EnableResourceNameDnsARecord": false,
            "EnableResourceNameDnsAAAARecord": false
        }
    },
```

I may use something like `jq` for filtering out the subnet id only:

```
    aws --region us-east-1 --output=json ec2 describe-subnets | jq ".Subnets[].SubnetId"
"subnet-aaaaaaaa"
"subnet-bbbbbbbb"
"subnet-cccccccc"
```

Instance types:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-instance-type-offerings.html

```
  describe-instance-types
[--dry-run | --no-dry-run]
[--instance-types <value>]
[--filters <value>]
[--cli-input-json <value>]
[--starting-token <value>]
[--page-size <value>]
[--max-items <value>]
```

Example - including a filter for free tier eligible instance types - be careful, there are only 750 free tier hours for t1.micro or t2.micro instances, so you can run one for a month or four of them for a week:

```
aws --region us-east-1 --output=json ec2 describe-instance-types  --filters Name=free-tier-eligible,Values=true
```

Output:

```
{
    "InstanceTypes": [
        {
            "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
            "CurrentGeneration": true,
            "FreeTierEligible": true,
            "SupportedUsageClasses": [
                "on-demand",
                "spot"
            ],
            "SupportedRootDeviceTypes": [
                "ebs"
            ],
            "SupportedVirtualizationTypes": [
                "hvm"
            ],
            "BareMetal": false,
            "Hypervisor": "xen",
            "ProcessorInfo": {
                "SupportedArchitectures": [
                    "i386",
                    "x86_64"
                ],
                "SustainedClockSpeedInGhz": 2.5
            },
            "VCpuInfo": {
                "DefaultVCpus": 1,
                "DefaultCores": 1,
                "DefaultThreadsPerCore": 1
            },
            "MemoryInfo": {
                "SizeInMiB": 1024
            },
            "InstanceStorageSupported": false,
            "EbsInfo": {
                "EbsOptimizedSupport": "unsupported",
                "EncryptionSupport": "supported",
                "NvmeSupport": "unsupported"
            },
            "NetworkInfo": {
                "NetworkPerformance": "Low to Moderate",
                "MaximumNetworkInterfaces": 2,
                "MaximumNetworkCards": 1,
                "DefaultNetworkCardIndex": 0,
                "NetworkCards": [
                    {
                        "NetworkCardIndex": 0,
                        "NetworkPerformance": "Low to Moderate",
                        "MaximumNetworkInterfaces": 2
                    }
                ],
                "Ipv4AddressesPerInterface": 2,
                "Ipv6AddressesPerInterface": 2,
  ....this is very long try it for yourself
```

From the instance type you may want to use the `SupportedRootDeviceTypes` value for the next query:

Describe images:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html

```
 describe-images
[--executable-users <value>]
[--filters <value>]
[--image-ids <value>]
[--owners <value>]
[--include-deprecated | --no-include-deprecated]
[--dry-run | --no-dry-run]
[--cli-input-json <value>]
[--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

Example:

```
aws --region us-east-1 --output=json ec2 describe-images --owners self amazon --filters "Name=root-device-type,Values=ebs"
```

Output:

```
{
"Images": [
    {
        "Architecture": "x86_64",
        "CreationDate": "2021-10-01T06:33:39.000Z",
        "ImageId": "ami-03ed02f0f58f6da3b",
        "ImageLocation": "amazon/amzn-ami-minimal-pv-2018.03.0.20211001.0-x86_64-ebs",
        "ImageType": "machine",
        "Public": true,
        "KernelId": "aki-5c21674b",
        "OwnerId": "137112412989",
        "PlatformDetails": "Linux/UNIX",
        "UsageOperation": "RunInstances",
        "State": "available",
        "BlockDeviceMappings": [
            {
                "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                "Ebs": {
                    "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                    "SnapshotId": "snap-0e7ecc707162605a2",
                    "VolumeSize": 2,
                    "VolumeType": "standard",
                    "Encrypted": false
                }
            }
        ],
        "Description": "Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0.20211001.0 x86_64 Minimal PV ebs",
        "EnaSupport": true,
        "Hypervisor": "xen",
        "ImageOwnerAlias": "amazon",
        "Name": "amzn-ami-minimal-pv-2018.03.0.20211001.0-x86_64-ebs",
        "RootDeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
        "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
        "SriovNetSupport": "simple",
        "VirtualizationType": "paravirtual",
        "DeprecationTime": "2023-10-01T06:33:39.000Z"
    },
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I know which values for the three parameters are free to my free tier account?

Comment: @Tim You can't. There is no option for that sadly.

Comment: Could you please clarify how these commands can be used to locate **free** tier resources, which OP is asking for?